# Two monitors one 23" hd and one 28" 4k

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have two monitors connected to my computer, I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1. One screen is set at full hd 1920x 1080 and the other monitor is 28" 4k set to 3840 x 2160. I have nvidia 760 display card. I want to have the 4k monitor in similar resolution as hd, everything is so small. I probably need to change the DPI. Now I just configure the 4k screen to 1920 so the screens are same. I have configured the nvidia to save the config but it does not save on start up.

How do I change the nvidia display so Ubuntu will use the x.conf correctly ?
How do I change the nvidia display so the 4k monitor will be in 4k native but the size of the font, windows, mouse and everything else will be the same as hd ?